# Access Last-Modified HTTP response header on Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, http-headers

I am trying to make a HEAD request and read Last-Modified header from the response.
So far I've been using [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) to do all of my async server communication, which worked fine, but for some reason [HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx).[Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.headers(v=vs.118).aspx) doesn't seem to contain Last-Modified response header, even though server does return it.

How do I access Last-Modified response header in Windows Phone 8.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the `Last-Modified` of the file you're downloading then take a look at

```C#
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
var reponse = await hc.GetAsync("http://www.chubosaurus.com/dogecoin_wp8.jpg");
```

Then look at the

```C#
reponse.Content.Headers.LastModified
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not using the GetAsync method in this case, but the Last-Modified header was indeed in Content.Headers.